# React state variable loses value after event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I render a form and a list. It works just fine at the initial load up:

> ```
>             <UsersList
>                 users={this.state.users}
>             />
>             <SendMessageForm
>                 sendMessage={this.addMessage}
>
>             />
> ```

However, when the SendMessageForm is submitted `this.state.users` loses its value and I get the error of `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Here is the SendMessageForm:

```
export default class SendMessageForm extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            message: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            message: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.sendMessage(this.state.message);
        this.setState({
            message: ''
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="MessageField">
                <form
                    onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    className="send-message-form">
                    <input
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.message}
                        placeholder="Type your message and hit ENTER"
                        type="text"
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the UserList:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class UsersList extends Component {
    render() {
            return (
                <div id="UList">
                    <ul className="users-list">
                        {this.props.users.map((user, index) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={index}>
                                    <span>{user}</span>
                                </li>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
export default UsersList;
```

Could you help me understand how the state variable users loses its value?

EDIT:

Adds message to the MessageList. MessageList works just fine, the problem is with the UsersList. By the way I am using Chatkit library.

```
addMessage(text) {
    this.state.currentUser.sendMessage({
        text,
        roomId: this.state.roomId.toString()
    })
        .catch(error => console.error('error', error));
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working, what does `addMessage` do?

Comment: There is a MessageList, that stores messages. addMessage add a message to the list. This works just fine. What do you mean by seems to be working? Where did you check?

Comment: see https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ufwkv?file=index.js

Comment: you should post code of your addMessage function. problem is most likely there

Comment: code is working fine on given link  stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ufwkv?file=index.js

Comment: Can you tell share with us the component that is using the UserList and SendMessageForm inside of it?

Comment: Added addMessage part of the code

Comment: I don't see a try block but you are using `.catch()`